# Angular 2 not making a http call when

Tags: angular, http, caching, rxjs

I have a custom event on which I need to fetch the account info. I see that the `fetchAccountInfo` function gets called from the `HostListener` but I don't see the call in network, instead the observable just returns the old value. Even Angular interceptor does not receive any call.

Following is mock representation of my code.

In `component.ts`

```
@HostListener('custom-event', ['$event'])
handleEventChange(e: any) {
  this.accountInfoService.fetchAccountInfo().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data); // gives old value
  });
}
```

In `service.ts`

```
public fetchAccountInfo(): Observable<IAccountInformation> {
  return this.httpClient
    .get<IAccountInformation>('accountInfoURL')
    .pipe(
      tap((accountInfo) => this.setAccountInfo(accountInfo))
    );
}

private setAccountInfo(accountInfo: IAccountInformation): void {
  this.accountInfoSubject$.next(accountInfo);
}
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening.

This issue is resolved when we add a random salt query at the end of API url `?q=new Date().getTime().toString()`

But I am looking for the reasons behind this issue and maybe a better way to handle this issue.

I have tried setting different `cache-control` value to request and response, but that did not help.

Please let me know if you need any more details or clarification.

Any help or clues are really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Any chance you have an interceptor performing some caching?

Comment: @BizzyBob Hey thanks for your comment, so we found the issue. It is indeed an interceptor doing the caching. But its now our own, we have an universal app and `TransferHttpCacheInterceptor` from `webpack:///node_modules/@nguniversal/common/fesm2015/common.js` is caching the API response. It returns the cached response because apparently the angular application is not stable when the API call is performed, so it uses the cached response at that time. We haven't found out why application is not stable at that time.

Comment: **But its not* our own